# flexbox: align self and align item are not woking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<td>
   <div class="paper" style="display:flex; ">
      <div class="row" style="height: 20px; background-color: "></div>
   </div>
</td>
```

In the `.paper, justify` content works fine but `align-items` wont work. where as in its child class `.row, align-self` wont work.
Before this `<td>` i have set a flex property as well. the code looks like this:

```
<td>
   <div class="wrapper" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="close" style="align-self: center;">
         <i class="icon fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="image ml-15">
         <img class="width-100" src="commercial/front-end/shop/lauren-winter-studio-top-natural_0190-cropped.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details pull-right ml-20" style="align-self: center;">
         <span>Cream Top</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="paper" style="display:flex; ">
      <div class="row" style="height: 20px; background-color: "></div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the width or height on the right direction of the parent element when you use align-self/align-item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide some hardcoded height and width to ".paper" class in order to use align-self/align-item.
       https://jsfiddle.net/akash94/thpub2ej/2/

```
.paper{
      display:flex;
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      border:1px solid lightblue;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center
      }

.row{
      align-self:flex-end;
    }
```